# How to print all output after taken multiple inputs in python?

Tags: python, for-loop

```
t = int(input().strip())
sum1=0

for t_itr in range(t):
    n = int(input().strip())
    
    for i in range(n):
      if i%3==0 or i%5==0:
        sum1=sum1+i
       
print(sum1)
```

'Given Result 
2 
10 
100 
2318 '

'Expected Input
2 
10 
100 
'Expected  Output 
23 
2318'

Comment: use a pen and paper, and try to simulate what each line does, or try stepping through the code using the debugger, and figure out where you need to put your print statements for your code to work as intended.

Comment: yeah ! I got answer. Thank you sir